# Poor formatting for RegExp format exception

Tags: dart

This is Dart 3.0.3 macos_x64, inside Flutter 3.10.4.

This code

```
  try {
    var re = RegExp(str, caseSensitive: false);
    // do something with 're'
  } on FormatException catch (e) {
    print("pattern '${str}' gives '${e}' ");
  }
```

gives this error on a bad name pattern like "[a-"

```
pattern '[a-' gives 'FormatException: Unterminated character class[a-'
```

To me, it looks like it needs a space after 'class' and before the actual bad pattern. Using "${e.message}" looks just as bad.

Am I doing something wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: You can't control the exception message that `RegExp`'s constructor builds - it isn't your problem. If you want this improved then file a bug with Dart's RegExp library. Don't try to parse the `FormatException`'s default `toString` output or message, as (in this case) it's an English-language human-readable string, not structured data.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the core Dart C++ code. [`ReportError`](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/a2dbcf7a56eff72019e2519859f2655a7bc730c1/runtime/vm/regexp_parser.cc#L435-L436) concats together the error message and the pattern without a space between them:

```cpp
const String& msg = String::Handle(
      String::Concat(String::Handle(String::New(message)), in()));
```

And in this case, `message` is:

```cpp
static const char* kUnterminated = "Unterminated character class";
```

File a bug with them.

Comment: Thanks. Reported: https://dartbug.com/52691